# How know state of connection in app

Tags: windows-store-apps

I use the next guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/hh700381.aspx
But connected property don't exist

```
var red = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,
            internet = red.getInternetConnectionProfile();

        console.log(internet.connected);
```

Answer (score 0):

That MSDN page is in error--the connected property doesn't exist. (I'll file a bug on that topic!).

If you don't have any connectivity, then getInternetConnectionProfile will return null to begin with.

You can see the correct code in scenario 1 of the Network information sample, http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Network-Information-Sample-63aaa201. This is where the code in that topic was originally taken, and clearly the two aren't in sync.

Comment: When i connected to any network, my connection might doesn't have access to internet. How i know if i have internet access?

Comment: In that case you want to enumerate available connections with getConnectionProfiles rather than getInternetConnectionProfile (described in the same topic you looked at originally). Then call the profile's getConnectivityLevel method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getnetworkconnectivitylevel.aspx) to get a NetworkConnectivity value which will tell you if it has Internet or not.